# How to get optional rout parameters in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a route that is declared in service provider :

```
     public function boot(){
       $router = $this->app['router'];
       $router->get('captcha/api/{config?}','\Hpd\Captcha\CaptchaController@getCaptchaApi')->middleware('web');
     }
```

As you can see config is a optional route parameters then I can omit it. But when I omit it the "api" injects to getCaptchaApi() method!!!!?.

Comment: Don't configure routes directly in the `RouteServiceProvider`. Configure them in the relevant routes file (`web` or `api`) or if this is a custom package, use [`loadRoutesFrom`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/packages#routes) to register your routes with Laravel.

Comment: yes, its a custom package. and want to publish it. I think if I use loadRoutesFrom, users who is using my package should define it in their route file!  @Peppermintology

Comment: Nope. If you define the routes and use `loadRoutesFrom` in your package `RouteServiceProvider` then they will automatically be available to the users of your package.